Access EKS ingress ALB timeout
I have an EKS cluster and installed "Amazon Load Balancer Controller", which looks fine in the following attached image and workloads was deployed along with ingress following the official article. Yaml file below:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: game-2048
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: deployment-2048
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: public.ecr.aws/l6m2t8p7/docker-2048:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: app-2048
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: service-2048
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-2048
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: ingress-2048
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: service-2048
              port:
                number: 80
          

k get ingress indicates it was deployed in the following attached image, however, I'm getting timeout when I access the address.

I have tried change Service type to "LoadBalancer" and access the service directly then it looks working in the screenshot

While monitoring the ingress controller logs, no logs updated.


Anybody can help? Thanks!

Have check the logs using kubectl describe ingress INGRESS_NAME ?

Solved but not pretty sure about the reason:
I changed the ALB listener port form 80 to 30080,then it works.
enter image description here
